# Sum 2 or more associative arrays values based on keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've searched around 1 h. It seems to be duplicate, but I can't find something to help me.

```
$a = array('aa'=>10, 'bb'=>2, 'cc'=>5);
$b = array('aa'=>1, 'bb'=>20, 'dd'=>11);
$c = array('aa'=>3);
$d = array('ee'=>5);
```

How can I sum all of this in one array which should look like:

```
$summed = array('aa'=>14,'bb'=>22,'cc'=>5,'dd'=>11,'ee'=>5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge all arrays and sum values if it's an array

```
$res = array_merge_recursive($a, $b, $c,$d);
foreach($res as &$x) {
    if (is_array($x)) {
       $x = array_sum($x); 
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/942471)

Comment: ...you _could_ even force the `$x` to an array and omit the conditional like: `$x = array_sum((array)$x);`  Either way, `array_merge_recursive()` is the best tool for the job because the arrays are associative.  An excellent piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
$summed=[] ;
foreach ([$a,$b,$c,$d] as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($summed[$k])) $summed[$k] = 0;
        $summed[$k]+=$v;
    }
}
print_r($summed);
```

Will outputs :

```
Array
(
    [aa] => 14
    [bb] => 22
    [cc] => 5
    [dd] => 11
    [ee] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array('aa'=>10, 'bb'=>2, 'cc'=>5);
$b = array('aa'=>1, 'bb'=>20, 'dd'=>11);
$c = array('aa'=>3);
$d = array('ee'=>5);

$arrays = [$a, $b, $c, $d];

$result = [];

foreach ($arrays as $value_array) {
    foreach ($value_array as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
            $result[$key] += $value;
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method that uses less looping than iterating the full arrays is to get all keys from the arrays and use array_column and array_sum.

```
$a = array('aa'=>10, 'bb'=>2, 'cc'=>5);
$b = array('aa'=>1, 'bb'=>20, 'dd'=>11);
$c = array('aa'=>3);
$d = array('ee'=>5);

$arr = [$a,$b,$c,$d];

$keys = array_keys(array_merge($a,$b,$c,$d)); //merge arrays and get keys ['aa','bb'] etc.
Foreach($keys as $key){
    // Sum column of 'aa', 'bb' etc from array
    $sums[$key] = array_sum(array_column($arr, $key));
}

Var_dump($sums);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZHtWf